# INSERT dentro de clausula WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Eu basicamente aprendi SQL com PostgreSQL, estou pela primeira vez fazendo uso do SQL Server e não consegui descobrir como fazer isso nele.
Digamos que eu tenha duas tabelas. A primeira é uma tabela genérica de transações (vendas, locações, reservas, etc.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]
(
    [id] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [client] INT NOT NULL, 
    [functionary] INT NOT NULL, 
    [dateTime] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    [value] MONEY NOT NULL, 
    [typeTransaction] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY ([id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_ToClients] FOREIGN KEY ([client]) REFERENCES [Clients]([person]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_ToFunctionaries] FOREIGN KEY ([functionary]) REFERENCES [Functionaries]([person]), 
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Transactions_value] CHECK ([value] >= 0), 
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Transactions_typeTransaction] CHECK ([typeTransaction] > 0 AND [typeTransaction] < 5) 
)
```

A segunda tabela é uma "tabela filha" chamada [Sales]. Ou seja, [Sales] "extende" a tabela [Transaction], simulando uma herança ([Sales] herda de [Transactions]).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales]
(
    [transact] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [status] TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY ([transact]), 
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Sales_status] CHECK ([status] > 0 AND [status] < 4), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales_ToTransactions] FOREIGN KEY ([transact]) REFERENCES [Transactions]([id]) 
)
```

Estou tentando criar uma store procedure para fazer inserções de [Sales], ou seja, a SP deve receber como parâmetro os valores de [Transactions]. Deve então primeiro inserir esses valores na tabela [Transactions] e depois pegar o identificador e fazer uma inserção em [Sales].

Em PostgreSQL eu resolvia dessa forma:

```
WITH trans AS 
(
    INSERT INTO public."Transactions"
    (
        client, functionary, dateTime, value
    )
    VALUES
    (
        spp_client, spp_functionary,spp_dateTime,spp_value
    )
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO public."Sales"( transact ) SELECT t.id FROM trans AS t;
```

Tentei fazer o mesmo em SQL Server mas estou recebendo erros de sintaxe do editor do VS.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSale]
    @spp_client AS int,
    @spp_functionary AS int,
    @spp_dateTime AS datetime,
    @spp_value AS money
AS
BEGIN

    WITH trans AS 
    (
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions]
        (
            [client], [functionary], [dateTime], [value]
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @spp_client, @spp_functionary,@spp_dateTime,@spp_value
        )
        OUTPUT INSERTED.id
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]( [transaction] ) SELECT t.id FROM trans AS t;
END
```

Estou recebendo erro de sintaxe no INSERT dentro do WITH e no OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas maneiras para fazer este tipo de operação. Uma é usando ***Common Table Expression* (CTE)** como no seu exemplo, e a outro é usando uma "**tabela temporária**".

Acredito que o erro que você reportou é por conta do uso do `OUTPUT`. A sintaxe correta não é essa.

---

### Exemplo 1, com CTE

```
WITH trans(id) AS 
(
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions]
    (
        [client], [functionary], [dateTime], [value]
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id
    VALUES
    (
        @spp_client, @spp_functionary, @spp_dateTime, @spp_value
    )
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]( [transact] ) SELECT t.id FROM trans AS t;
```

### Exemplo 2, com "tabela temporária"

```
    DECLARE @myTempID AS TABLE (id bigint);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions]
    (
        [client], [functionary], [dateTime], [value]
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @myTempID
    VALUES
    (
        @spp_client, @spp_functionary, @spp_dateTime, @spp_value
    );

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]( [transact] ) SELECT t.id FROM @myTempID AS t;
```

Não consigo testar no momento. Tente executar e retorne se algo estiver errado.

Comment: Eu já havia tentado da primeira forma, mas o Visual Studio acusa [erro](http://oi67.tinypic.com/11vjyg1.jpg) de sintaxe

Comment: Mesmo colocando o `OUTPUT` antes do `VALUES` e adicionando o parâmetro id na declaração `WITH trans(id) AS` ?

Comment: Sim, dei copy e paste no seu código.

Comment: Estou em dúvida se SQL Server aceita `INSERT` em clausulas `WITH` pois só encontro exemplos com `SELECT`